# javascript interval not being cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am aware that this question has popped up a lot and believe me I have tried all the solutions on them. My question is as simple as the title, the `clearInterval()` function is not working as expected.

```
var newsCheck_handle;
var getNewsTime_handle; 
var originalTitle = document.title; //for title attribute update in newsCHeck function
if (url === 'Home'){
     newsCheck_handle = setInterval(function(){newsCheck(originalTitle)},1000);
     getNewsTime_handle = setInterval(function(){getNewsTime()},120000);
     $("#refreshFeed").on('click', loadNew); //load new news on click
}
else {//stop functions if not on homepage
    clearInterval(newsCheck_handle);
    clearInterval(getNewsTime_handle);
}
```

I have tried setting the `var`'s at the same level as the interval and not before but that does not work. Also tried `window.clearInterval()`, `self.setInterval()`.

Just in case its required. Here's the `newsCheck` function. The same effect happens with both of them and they're reasonably similar functions.

```
function newsCheck(originalTitle){
var objts = $(".newsItem:first").data("ts");
var objid = $(".newsItem:first").data("id");
var objevent = $(".newsItem:first").data("event");
var ids = $.makeArray(objid); //variable of IDS
var ts = $.makeArray(objts); //variable of ts
var event = $.makeArray(objevent); //variable of ts

if (objts != null && objid != null){
    $.get("../AJAX/get_feed_updates.php",{ ID: ids, ts: ts, event: event },function(result){   
        if (result > 0) {   
            document.title = '(' + result + ') ' + originalTitle;
            if (result == 1){// no plurals
                $("#refreshFeed").html(result + ' more news item.').fadeIn("slow");
            }    
            if (result > 1){ //plurals
                $("#refreshFeed").fadeIn(500).html(result + ' more news items.');
            } 
        }//close if result
    });//close get
}// close if ts
}//close function
```

Comment: How is the first snippet executed? I have a hunch that the interval either isn't even being started, or your conditional is *always* true.

Comment: @KevinB I have used `console.log()` to check that. The condition is not always true. If i log something in the else clause it will on log that if the condition is not true. The interval is being started as I have logged something within the function.

Comment: Can you answer kevin's question though?  How is this called/where is this code located.  Could this be called multiple times in a row with "url === HOME" before coming up false once and only clearing the last one?  Are those variables defined **within** a function, meaning they are cleared with each invocation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you start it many times? So you overwrite the timer every time and you only clear the last one.

Try this so it starts once, if it's not started yet

```
if (url === 'Home'){
     newsCheck_handle || (newsCheck_handle = setInterval(function(){newsCheck(originalTitle)},1000));
     getNewsTime_handle || (getNewsTime_handle = setInterval(function(){getNewsTime()},120000));
     $("#refreshFeed").on('click', loadNew); //load new news on click
}
else {//stop functions if not on homepage
    clearInterval(newsCheck_handle);
    clearInterval(getNewsTime_handle);
    newsCheck_handle = getNewsTime_handle = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Sadly this still has the same effect

Comment: try to print the timer to the console each time, to make sure you start and clear the same one.